# Idiomatic route structure for Rails model that belongs_to multiple parent models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**EDIT**: Please see updated base modelling information at the bottom of this post.

I would like to write an ActiveRecord model that has two `belongs_to` associations.

`base.rb`:

```
class Base < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :vehicle
    belongs_to :driver
end
```

`vehicle.rb`:

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :drivers
    has_one  :base
end
```

`driver.rb`:

```
class Driver < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :vehicle
    has_one    :base
end
```

`Vehicle` is the parent model for both `Driver` and `Base`, but the domain model requires at least one combined Vehicle/Driver association for a `Base` to exist.

My `routes.rb` right now:

```
resources :vehicles do
    resources :drivers
end
```

A route to a driver looks like this:

`/vehicles/:vehicle_id/drivers/:id`

How do I setup the routes for my new `Base` model and what would the URL look like? Should it exist as a nested resource under `:drivers`? Is this idiomatic Rails? Should I reconsider my data model approach? Your inputs are appreciated.

What are bases modelling? A Driver must affiliate his Vehicle with a Base to get a specific kind of insurance. Vehicles have a parent association, Insured, who owns the Vehicle. Insureds can drive their own Vehicle or hire Drivers, hence the reason Driver is a child of Vehicle. One Vehicle can have many Drivers, but a Driver can only work with one Vehicle. Once a Vehicle is affiliated with a Base, all future Drivers for that Vehicle must also affiliate with that base, unless the affiliation is changed at a later date. It is uncommon to see more than two Drivers working with a Vehicle.

Comment: To me, the word `Base` implies that there could be more than one vehicle and/or driver there (although you've made it a `belongs_to` association instead of a `has_many`). If that's the case, nesting is probably not the right thing to do. At the moment, a `resource` route seems more appropriate than a `resources` route for a nested vehicle's or driver's `base`.

Comment: what is a `Base` modeling?  That word doesn't mean much to me in this context

Comment: @AaronBreckenridge, please see my updated post (the bottom paragraph). At the moment, I have already decided that Bases will be a singular resource, I'm trying to figure out the best place to put them. I think I might nest it under the Drivers resource, and then set up a `has_one :through` association for Vehicles so Bases can be easily accessed.

Comment: @Fam I have to echo Aaron.  Given your description of `Base`, it sounds like it should have `has_many` associations and the vehicle and driver should `belong_to` it.  Otherwise, the idea of all drivers for a vehicle being affiliated with the same base breaks down - since only one base can exist for a given vehicle/driver pair.  Having a shared base object seems like it would improve data integrity without functionally changing your domain model.

Comment: @ChrisHall, thank you for your input. What would the route structure look like for your suggestion? Should `Base` exist as a top level resource alongside `Insured`?

Comment: @Fam i think the route structure is less important than the model setup. You can easily change the routes at any time.

Comment: @Fam for maximum RESTful-ness, I would say that all of your objects should probably be accessible from the top level, nesting only as circumstance requires.  For example, having a route for `/vehicle/:id/base` probably makes sense.  Personally, I try to avoid routes like `bases/:base_id/vehicles/:vehicle_id` unless doing so allows me to do something application specific that just routing to `/vehicles/:id` wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside the specific models referenced, answering the question of routes for resources with multiple parent models seems more straightforward.

Given a structure similar to:

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :first_parent
  belongs_to :second_parent
end

class FirstParent < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :child
end

class SecondParent < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :child
end
```

I might go for routes like:

```
# This makes changing all parents easier
concern :has_child do
  resource :child
end

resources :first_parents, concerns: :has_child

resources :second_parents, concerns: :has_child

# Rails may be smart enough for us to use :children instead of :childs
resources :children do
  resource :first_parent
  resource :second_parent
end
```

In this case, using `resource` instead of `resources` makes the resulting paths more representative of the actual relationships.  E.G. referencing a parent's child would use a path like `first_parents/:id/child` - assuming I'm correctly reading the documentation.

Further, I wouldn't recommend a combined route of some kind because only one parent resource is really required to look up the child resource.

However, if your parent models have many children, you'll need to use `resources :child` since the resulting record is no longer unique.

In this case, I still wouldn't recommend some kind of combined route since it doesn't do a good job of explaining the relationship between them all.  There is some potential benefit in that you could use it to, for example, look up the children shared by a given pair of parents, but I feel like that would be better served by a child search route of some kind.